# What is the difference between builtin voltage and cutin voltage in pn diode?

Tags: pn-junction

I am little bit confused that how these two are different.

Comment: According to Millman & Halkias ("Electronic Devices and Circuits", 1967), they are synonymous. From p. 128: "...there exist a cutin, offset, breakpoint or threshold voltage V_gamma below which the current is very small (say, less then 1% of maximum rated value.) Beyond V_gamma the current rises rapidly"

Answer (score 1):

I've not heard the term 'cutin', or perhaps 'cut-in', voltage before. This is more commonly called the 'threshhold' voltage.

It will refer to the forward voltage that is commonly held to be necessary to get a forward biased diode to conduct. For silicon, this is often given as 0.7v, with shottky and germanium being around 0.3v. LEDs have higher voltages from 1.6v for red to 3v for blue.

In fact, diodes conduct at all potentials, including reverse. It's just that the conduction tends to be insignificant in the context of typical electronic circuits needing (say) a \$10\mu A\$ to 10mA range, for which the voltage *will* be close to the above mentioned voltages. For the accuracy that the temperature coefficient permits, most engineers say that diodes conduct at the threshhold voltage, and understand that they are dealing in a crude approximation.

The 'built-in' voltage refers to the difference in energy of the doped semiconductors that form the diode junction. See [wikipedia's entry for p-n junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction). This is constant, is a function of the doping densities of the semiconductors, and is of the same sort of order as the threshhold voltage, which gives rise to the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Most diodes have a logarithmic equation linking diode voltage and diode current.
Often a 1mA diode current occurs with diode voltage *near* 0.6 volts.
Every decrease of 0.018 volts across the diode will reduce the current by 2:1.
Every decrease of 0.060 volts will reduce the current by 10:1.
Lets put this into a table.

Vdiode     Idiode

0.600      1mA

0.540      0.1mA

0.480      0.01mA

0.420      1microAmp

0.360      100 nanoAmps

0.300       10 nanoAmps

0.240        1 nanoAmps

At lower currents, this log-behavior becomes less accurate.

Similarly, depending on size of the internal diode junction, the log-behavior becomes less accurate at currents above 1mA, because the internal resistance of the silicon begins to dominate the I_V curve.